# Using Puppeteer to collect links of a page and open those links to scrape data

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have to scrape data of products from a list, but the data resides in the pages of those products. For example, let's say I'd like to fetch the `.product-image` of the product page.

The code so far successfully fetches each URL and adds to an array, but I'm not sure where to go from here, as using `page` returns `Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: page is not defined` when using it outside of `urls` for some reason.

```
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 0, waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

  await page.goto(siteSearchUrl + 1);
  await page.screenshot({ path: "carpet.png" });

  const urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll("li.product-item");
    const productLinks = [];
    console.log(page);
    items.forEach((item) => {
      const productLink = item
        .querySelector("a.product-image") // NOT the product image, it's the link.
        .getAttribute("href");
      productLinks.push(`${siteUrl + productLink}`);
    });

    productLinks.forEach((link) => {
      page.screenshot({ path: link + ".png" });
    }, page);
  });

  await browser.close();
  return Promise.resolve(urls);
})();
```

How exactly do I collect the data from each of the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use `page` inside of `page.evaluate`.

You get `ReferenceError: page is not defined` due to [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) executes the script in the page context (e.g. your `console.log(page)` is logged into the Chromium's console, and not to Node's console), other puppeteer methods (like [`page.screenshot`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.0&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions)) cannot be run on the client side, but in puppeteer only. So you need to move it outside.

E.g.:

```
const urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const productLinks = []
  ...
  productLinks.push(...)
  ...
  return productLinks
})

for (const url of urls) {
  await page.goto(url)
  await page.screenshot({ path: url + '.png' })
}
```

### Edit

I fixed the example above. You may find you are able to solve the problem by using `page.$eval`, [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) more concisely.

```js
const hrefs = await page.$$eval('li.product-item > a.product-image', elements => elements.map(el => el.href))
const urls = hrefs.map(el => siteUrl + el)

for (const url of urls) {
  await page.goto(url)
  await page.screenshot({ path: url + '.png' })
}
```

Comment: Will not `productLinks ` be udefined inside `page.evaluate()` and empty afterwards without array transferring between the contexts?

Comment: true. indeed, I forgot that it is tricky to populate array from page context. I will re-compose my example to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have one request - what would pagination look with your code? The query for pagination is  ?page=1.

Comment: wow, I think it worths a new question, I am not sure if my comment will be useful to achieve what you need. puppeteer doesn't always respect GET parameters in the URL. if you want to turn the page after you are done with the scraping of the current page, you could just click on the next page button like a real user does: `await page.click('.next-page-btn')`